# Were short-sleeved jerseys used in-game during the 2022-2023 season?

Tags: nba, uniform

As a [fashion statement](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-is-the-motivation-behind-short-sleeve-jerseys-in-the-nba/2340#2340), Golden state sported short-sleeved jerseys a decade ago.

Game 7 of the 2016 NBA Finals consisted of the Cavaliers wearing short-sleeved jerseys.

However, I haven't seen much in the way of short-sleeved jerseys as of late.

Were short-sleeved jerseys used in-game during the 2022-2023 NBA season?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there are any one-offs that it's missing, but [basketballjerseyarchive.com](https://basketballjerseyarchive.com/nba-2022-23-jerseys/) shows all the jerseys for 2022-2023 are sleeveless.   They do show the short-sleeved jersey for both the Warriors and the Cavaliers that you mention in previous years.

Just scanning by eye (so I could have missed something), I don't see any short-sleeves after the 2016-2017 season.  Many of the teams that year had a short-sleeve version.